# OpenSSL shared compilation on Windows issue

Tags: windows, qt, openssl

I want to compile OpenSSL libs as dynamic (shared) libs. I use **openssl-1.0.2l** and **Visual Studio 2017** (Windows 10) and it all compiles well.

**Compilation commands:**

```
perl configure debug-VC-WIN32 --prefix="C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.0.2l\shared\x86\debug" no-asm

ms\do_ms

nmake -f ms\nt.mak

nmake -f ms\nt.mak install
```

The problem is that `OpenSSL` libs are static. I checked it by this command (for example):

`lib /list libeay32.lib`

Screenshot

[image]

Any ideas how to compile it as dynamic libs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed it by changing `nt.mak` to `ntdll.mak` on all commands. Now it's dynamic libs.The issue is resolved.

**Screenshot:**

Image issue resolved

[image]